# Python - How to store desired amount of objects of a class in a list?

Tags: python

I would like to make a list that stores all objects of the `JoJo` class in a list according to the desired amount of users.

Example: If I want to create two users of the `JoJo class`, the code will allow me to enter the `name` and `stand` of these users and print them at the end of the code. The necessary changes for this will be on the `main.py` page.

- `jojo.py`

```
    class JoJo:
        # Construct
        def __init__(self):
            self.status_stand = False
        # Destruct
        def __del__(self):
            print (f"The user {self.getName()} was deleted by the destruct.")
        # Getter
        def getName(self): return self.name
        def getStand(self): return self.stand
        # Setter
        def setName(self, noma): self.name = name
        def setStand(self, stand): self.stand = stand
        # Method activeStand()    
        def activeStand(self):
            if self.status_stand:
                print(f"{self.getStand()} is already invoked.")
            else:
                self.status_stand = True
                print(f"{self.getStand()} was invoked.")
        # Méthod desactiveStand()
        def desactiveStand(self):
            if self.status_stand == False:
                print(f"{self.getStand()} is already hidden.")
            else:
                self.status_stand = False
                print(f"{self.getStand()} was hidden.")
        # Method talk()        
        def talk(self): 
            print(f"Name: {self.getName()} | Stand: {self.getStand()}")
            print ("Stand status: " + {True: "Active.", False: "Inactive."}[self.status_stand])
            self.activeStand() if self.status_stand else self.desactiveStand()
```

- `main.py`

```
    from jojo import JoJo
        
    jojo = JoJo()
    while True:
      name = str(input("Enter username: "))
      if (len(nome.strip()) <= 0):
        print("Username cannot be empty.")
      else:
        jojo.setNome(name.title())
        break
    while True:
      stand = str(input(f"Enter the name of the {jojo.getName()} stand: "))
      if (len(stand.strip()) <= 0):
        print(f"The name of {jojo.getNome()} stand cannot be empty.")
      else:
        jojo.setStand(stand.title())
        break
    jojo.talk()
    del jojo
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a list object.  Assuming we accept user names until a blank value tells us to stop:

```
jojo_list = list()
while True:
    name = input("Enter username: ")
    if name.strip() == '':
        break
    jojo = JoJo()
    jojo.setName(name.strip().title())
    jojo_list.append(jojo)
```

Now you can simply loop over your list of jojo objects and do things to them:

```
for jojo in jojo_list:
    print(jojo.getName())
```

Details on list objects: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html